# How do I call a getter from another Substrate module?

Tags: rust, substrate

I have two modules, MyCore and Special. MyCore has a public getter:

```
pub fn get_core_account() -> Option<T::AccountId>
```

Which gets an accountId. If I call this from Special in a simple manner:

```
let core_account = MyCore::get_core_account();
```

then rustc complains that it can't infer the type, which is odd because the public setters don't need further info. So I make the type explicit

```
let core_account: Option<T::AccountId> = MyCore::get_core_account();
```

But this triggers demands for type specifiers on the call, so we elaborate:

```
let core_account: Option<T::AccountId> = MyCore::<T>::get_core_account();
```

At which point rust complains that it can't find get_core_account, because Special doesn't have a restriction to implement `MyCore::Trait`. But I don't want Special to implement `MyCore::Trait`! I want to call a getter!

Perhaps I'm missing something regarding the use of T here - in theory, Special is a trait templated over some T, which we can implement using a Test class if we implement the required types.

Does Special really need to implement `MyCore::Trait`?

Comment: [mcve] not included

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is possible, yet you are probably doing something wrong which is not clearly demonstrated in the question. Would be very helpful if you post the `Trait` definitions of both modules.

---

> Does Special really need to implement MyCore::Trait?

No. You might have to make it a trait bound though.

Basically, you have two options in such cases:

1. If your `Core` is something that all other modules will depend on, similar to `frame-system`, you can explicitly depend on it. Note that this path should be taken with care and you don't want to create too big of a monolithic software with this mindset. Nonetheless, in that case, you can just do:

```rust
// in special.rs
// This is needed because then we can pass `T` into `mycore::Module<_>`.
pub trait Trait: mucore::Trait {
   ...
}

// and then later on you can call:
<mycore::Module<T>>:: get_core_account()
```

This seems like the approach that you wanted to take.

2. Alternatively, you can bind the two modules together without this explicit dependency. This is useful for when you want your `Special` to receive the getter eventually, but you don't really care who provides it. Or in other words, if multiple candidates can provide this getter and you want to be generic over it.

For this, you first need a common trait definition.

```rust
// in some common dependency
trait CoreGetterProvider<AccountId> {
  fn getter() -> Option<AccountId>;
}
```

and your `Special` would express:

```rust
pub trait Trait {
  // .. other stuff. Assuming that it has a common AccountId with Core. 
  type Getter: CoreGetterProvider<Self::AccountId>
}
```

And your `Core` implements it

```rust
// in Core.rs
impl<T: Trait> CoreGetterProvider<T::AccountId> for Module<T> { ... }
```

Finally, when building the runtime, you can pass the `Core` module to `Special`.

```rust
impl core::Trait for Runtime { ... }
impl special::Trait for Runtime {
  type Getter = core::Module<Runtime> // or just `Core`. construct_runtime! creates this type alias. 
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! My only concern with the latter approach (which I agree is preferable generally) is that I won't be able to run unit tests in Special, unless I can instantiate the Special test type using maybe the MyCore test type...?

Comment: This is not an answer, don't try to answer incomplete question, quoting yourself "yet you are probably doing something wrong which is not clearly demonstrated in the question"

Comment: @PhilH you can mock the other module and always provide a dummy implementation for testing. Would be good if you also update your question to a "Minimal, Reproducible Example".